# Lyx outline pane and menu truncating titles after N chars

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx

using Lyx I've encountered the following problem: In the outline pane section's and subsection's text are truncated after a certain number of chars. The same limit seem to be applied in the "Navigate" menu's TOC.
This make working with long section titles difficult and I can't navigate efficiently the document.
I've searched around for a solution, nothing found.
Is this a bug or a feature? Is there a work-around?

Comment: The work around is easy if you happen to have Ubuntu and can recompile. Just change the line `static int const TOC_ENTRY_LENGTH = 40;` and recompile (see Torbjorn's link).

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended behaviour, as far as I can tell from the comments to http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/9572. As such your only option would be to add a feature request in the bug tracker to disable the truncating.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to scottkosty and Torbjørn T. for directions.

Indeed, I recompiled Lyx changing source file `/src/insets/Inset.h`
from

```
static int const TOC_ENTRY_LENGTH = 40;
```

to

```
static int const TOC_ENTRY_LENGTH = 400;
```

On **Lyx 2.1.4** it is on line **77** of aforementioned file.